# How to make bootstrap example full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found this piece of code for a timeline I need for a website online. You can see how it looks at https://jsfiddle.net/ . My question is why is it so small? I don't see anything in the css setting the size, is this a bootstrap feature?

Code also posted below:

```
<head>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
<h4>Latest News</h4>
<ul class="timeline">
<li>
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.totoprayogo.com/#">New Web Design</a>
<a href="#" class="float-right">21 March, 2014</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque scelerisque diam non nisi semper, et elementum lorem ornare. Maecenas placerat facilisis mollis. Duis sagittis ligula in sodales vehicula....</p>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">21 000 Job Seekers</a>
<a href="#" class="float-right">4 March, 2014</a>
<p>Curabitur purus sem, malesuada eu luctus eget, suscipit sed turpis. Nam pellentesque felis vitae justo accumsan, sed semper nisi sollicitudin...</p>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Awesome Employers</a>
<a href="#" class="float-right">1 April, 2014</a>
<p>Fusce ullamcorper ligula sit amet quam accumsan aliquet. Sed nulla odio, tincidunt vitae nunc vitae, mollis pharetra velit. Sed nec tempor nibh...</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
ul.timeline {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
ul.timeline:before {
    content: ' ';
    background: #d4d9df;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 29px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 400;
}
ul.timeline > li {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
ul.timeline > li:before {
    content: ' ';
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #22c0e8;
    left: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 400;
}
```

Thanks for any help, as you can tell I am not the best developer but I would really like to add this feature on my site.

Comment: Do not post empty links. Make a public fiddle; only then post a jsfiddle link in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the class of div from ".col-md-6, .offset-md-3" to ".col-12" and if and it is not sufficient then change ".container" to ".container-fluid".

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h4>Latest News</h4>
          <ul class="timeline">
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.totoprayogo.com/#">New Web Design</a>
            <a href="#" class="float-right">21 March, 2014</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque scelerisque diam non nisi semper, et elementum lorem ornare. Maecenas placerat facilisis mollis. Duis sagittis ligula in sodales vehicula....</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">21 000 Job Seekers</a>
            <a href="#" class="float-right">4 March, 2014</a>
             <p>Curabitur purus sem, malesuada eu luctus eget, suscipit sed turpis. Nam pellentesque felis vitae justo accumsan, sed semper nisi sollicitudin...</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Awesome Employers</a>
            <a href="#" class="float-right">1 April, 2014</a>
            <p>Fusce ullamcorper ligula sit amet quam accumsan aliquet. Sed nulla odio, tincidunt vitae nunc vitae, mollis pharetra velit. Sed nec tempor nibh...</p>
           </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
```